# I need to change an int argument to a double. But the int argument will be input by the user

Tags: java, int, double

I'm not sure how to do this.

if i had code such as:

```
public void printReceipt (int price, int date, int till)

system.out.println(price * date + till)
```

So when the user enters 3 integers to begin with, I need the method to return a double for `price * date` even though they are first took as a single int

Not sure how to change an int to a double inside a method like this. Hoping for some help, thank you

Comment: Well you *could* just cast to `double`, but it's unlikely to be particularly useful. (It's not clear what sense it makes to multiply a price by a date, either.) Currently the method you've shown doesn't return *anything* though - it's a `void` method. Please clarify your question - until you make it clearer, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help.

Comment: You have three integers, how should a multiplication return a double?

Comment: The date and price are just names I made up. I basically want to print out a kind of table of information. However i need the information in the table to be presented as a double, not as an int.

Comment: @JonSkeet ^....

Comment: So cast the result to a double before you print it. Or just use an implicit conversion: `double result = price * date + till; System.out.println(result);`

Answer (score 0):

An `int` is smaller than a `double`, so you can simply assign an int to a double:

`double result = price * date * till;`

Comment: I cannot use result though as it does not actually return a result. I am using 'system.out.println' instead to print a few lines of information.

Comment: @ShanNicole: From your question: "I need the method to return a double". Now you're saying "it does not actually return a reslut". Please try to be clear and consistent in your question, otherwise it's really hard to help you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use .ToDouble() methode

Comment: How would I write this though in the method?